# Predictive classification including varying information about classes

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, prior

I'd appreciate help conceptualizing a problem. I constructed a supervised training set where user inputs carry the correct classification. In building a classification model, I'll strip out the correct class label and try to predict it using features linked to the inputs.

What makes this more challenging than a simple classification problem (at least for me!) is that there are known, class-specific details that can vary on a day-to-day basis.

For instance, some days Class A might be much more likely than Class B (empirically). So I'd want to pull the model toward Class A on some days.

Does this type of problem have a name? My searching has not been super productive, and I think I could use some help with the right terminology. Second to this, I'd also appreciate any thoughts about promising solutions to investigate. Bayesian hierarchical models that make use of this prior information?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your classification task simply has a [time-series](/questions/tagged/time-series) aspect to it. You could look through [previous questions tagged both "time-series" and "classification"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series%2bclassification).

How to leverage this will depend on how specifically the time impacts the class membership. You could have [seasonality](/questions/tagged/seasonality) (in summer, class foo is more likely than bar), which can often be handled by periodic transformations, e.g., harmonics or periodic Gaussian splines. You might have [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities) (foo is more likely than bar on Mondays, but the effect is more pronounced in summer than in winter). You could have long- or short-term trends. Or you could have [interaction](/questions/tagged/interaction)s between time and other features.

Comment: Thanks, @Stephan_Kolassa. Good idea. The time periods will be days (maybe hours) over a few weeks—so not seasons—but point taken.

Comment: There can certainly be intra-weekly seasonality, or even intra-daily. "Seasonality", in time series parlance, is any pattern that repeats regularly, no matter how long the cycle is.